# Add element to Seq[String] in Scala

Tags: java, list, scala, seq

I'm trying to create a list of words in Scala. I'm new to the language. I have read a lot of posts about how you can't edit immutable objects, but none that has managed to show me how to create the list I need in Scala. I am using var to initialise, but this isn't helping.

```
var wordList = Seq.empty[String]

for (x <- docSample.tokens) {
  wordList.++(x.word)
}

println(wordList.isEmpty)
```

I would greatly appreciate some help with this. I understand that objects are immutable in Scala (although vars are not), but what I need is some concise information about why the above always prints "true", and how I can make the list add the words contained in docSample.tokens.word.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like `val wordList = docSample.tokens.map(_.word)`  No mutable variables required. Or `flatMap`, if `word` happens to be another `Seq`.. it's unclear from your post.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a val and still keep the wordlist immutable like this:

```
val wordList: Seq[String] = 
  for {
    x <- docSample.tokens     
  } yield x.word

println(wordList.isEmpty)
```

Alternatively:

```
val wordList: Seq[String] = docSample.tokens.map(x => x.word)     

println(wordList.isEmpty)
```

Or even:

```
val wordList: Seq[String] = docSample.tokens map (_.word)     

println(wordList.isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can append to an immutable `Seq` and reassign the `var` to the result by writing

```
wordList :+= x.word
```

That expression desugars to `wordList = wordList :+ word` in the same way that `x += 1` desugars to `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
wordList = wordList:+(x.word)
```

Answer (score -1):

After a few hours, I posted a question, and a minute later figured it out.

wordList = (x.word)::wordList

This code solves it for anyone who comes across the same problem.

Comment: There's no need to use mutable `var` wordList here.