# Error adding element to mutable Seq

Tags: scala, append, mutable, seq

I'm wondering, why this doesn't work:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
var array: mutable.Seq[Int] = mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
array += 5
```

I get an error stating that `+=` works only for strings, why is this?

```
error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]
  Expression does not convert to assignment because:
    type mismatch;
     found   : Int(5)
     required: String
    expansion: array = array.$plus(5)
       array += 5
             ^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add element to Seq\[String\] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579853/add-element-to-seqstring-in-scala)

Comment: Using both `var` and a mutable collection is conflicting. Better to declare the mutable collection as `val`.

Comment: @cchantep If I do that I won't be able to mutate the collection... `"Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable"`

Comment: Have a look a the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Seq). Anyway, using `var` with a mutable type doesn't make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to [append to the end](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/mutable/Seq.html#+:(elem:A):scala.collection.mutable.Seq[A]), try the following:

```
array :+= 5
```

If you want to [prepend to its beginning](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/mutable/Seq.html#+:(elem:A):scala.collection.mutable.Seq[A]), do the following:

```
array +:= 5
```

I guess your assumption `+` is defined for mutable `Seq`s, but it is not. An implicit conversion is present (in `Predef`) to `String`s, so `+=` is tried to work as String concatenation.

Comment: Right. If you want to prepend/append, use a `Buffer`, not a `mutable.Seq`.